# Gostaria de pegar um elemento de uma pagina, através de suas "coordenadas"?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês, pois foi pedido a mim para desenvolver uma extensão para o google chrome, que pegue um determinado valor de uma determinada pagina, porem não tenho muito conhecimento em programação com javascript, alguém poderia me ajudar? vi algo relacionado com DOM, porem apenas encontrei para pegar este elemento por ID, CLASS ou METHOD, mas nenhum destes elementos e único na pagina que desejo pegar a informação
Dês de já agradeço

Comment: Poderia dar mais informações, tipo como o código que você está tentando pegar essas "cordenadas".

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Não entendi direito, tente usar

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("coloque uma tag html(div, p etc.)")
```

Comment: Poderia ser algo como
document.getElementsByTagName("body(table, tbody, tr, td)")
e como posso me referir a uma determinada td, por exemplo, quero a 3° TD desse TR